# CasperJS fill adwords keyword planner

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

I can't fill the adwords textarea in keyword planner.

1. I'm login google account : ok
2. I go to keyword planner : ok
3. Click for show menu : ok
4. fill textarea : no ???
5. Click button : ok

What can I do?

Part of code :

```
  casper.thenEvaluate(function () {
    document.querySelector('#gwt-debug-keywords-text-area').textContent = "test";
});
```

Entire code :

```
// requires
var utils = require('utils');
var casper = require('casper').create({
verbose: true,
logLevel: "debug",
waitTimeout: 5000
});

var email = 'email';
var passwd = 'passwd';

//login
casper.start('http://adwords.google.com');

casper.thenEvaluate(function login(email, passwd) {
    document.querySelector('#Email').setAttribute('value', email);
    document.querySelector('#Passwd').setAttribute('value', passwd);
    document.querySelector('form').submit();
}, {email:email, passwd:passwd});

//go to keyword planner
casper.thenOpen('https://adwords.google.com/ko/KeywordPlanner/Home?');

casper.wait(1000, function() {});

casper.thenEvaluate(function () {
    var element = document.querySelector( '#gwt-debug-splash-panel-search-selection-input' );
    var event = document.createEvent( 'MouseEvents' );
    event.initMouseEvent( 'click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0 );
    element.dispatchEvent( event );
});
//HERE
casper.thenEvaluate(function () {
    document.querySelector('#gwt-debug-keywords-text-area').textContent = "test";
});

casper.thenEvaluate(function () {   
    var element = document.querySelector( '#gwt-debug-search-button-content' );
    var event = document.createEvent( 'MouseEvents' );
    event.initMouseEvent( 'click', true, true, window, 1, 0, 0 );
    element.dispatchEvent( event ); 
});

casper.then(function() {
    this.capture('exit.png');
    });

casper.run();
```

See the capture : http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=939611exit.png

Comment: I just try to fill the form with the javascript console and neither document.querySelector('#gwt-debug-keywords-text-area').textContent = 'test'; nor document.querySelector('#gwt-debug-keywords-text-area').value = 'test'; show a modification. Maybe google protect this area or an event must be triggered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're assuming that Google's playing nice with their HTML and that the '#gwt-debug-keywords-text-area' ID is unique... but it is not. Try with your browser's console :

document.querySelectorAll('#gwt-debug-keywords-text-area')

You'll see that there are multiple elements with the same id... you'll find one of those to be the one you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I've never had success with using jQuery and Casperjs to send textarea to the screen, I'd love to see this working because I would use it.  Instead I just use `Casper.sendKeys`